# Customized Node Display for 'Document Template' Content-Type

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I want to filter the nodes of content-type `Document Template`. I know this can be done with `.tpl.php` files.

I was wondering, what was the right file name convention. I tried the the naming convention but it does not work.

```
node--document template.tpl.php
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where did I go wrong?

You used the wrong format. Replace the space with a `-`:

```
node--document-template.tpl.php
```